# Metro-Style AppBar in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, microsoft-metro, silverlight-5.0

I really like the AppBar UI and UX found in the upcoming Metro apps (Windows 8).  I was wondering if anyone had already duplicated this in a Silverlight application, e.g. version 5 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that I created:
http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/silverlight-metro-app-bar.html

Comment: Perfect! (Thought I had closed this out a long time ago!)